# Expectation of a maximum function

Tags: probability, expectation

Given for some $y_k$,
\begin{align}
w_k &= \begin{cases}
0 &\text{w.p. } \frac{1}{4} \\
1 &\text{w.p. } \frac{2}{4} \\
2 &\text{w.p. } \frac{1}{4}
\end{cases} \\
L_k(y_k) &= E\left[\max\{0,-y_k+w_k\}\right] +  E\left[\max\{0,y_k-w_k\} \right] \\
\end{align}
How do you apply the expectation to the maximum functions? Is it simply,
\begin{align}
E\left[\max\{0,-y_k+w_k\}\right] &= \max\{E[0]\,E[-y_k+w_k]\}\\
&= \max\{0,\frac{1}{4}(-y_k+0) + \frac{2}{4}(-y_k+1) + \frac{1}{4}(-y_k+2)\} 
\end{align}

Comment: What is $y_k $?

Comment: @Nitish $y_k$ is a decision variable (this question is part of a dynamic programming problem). For the purpose of this question, it is simply a fixed variable.

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably do it this way:
\begin{align}
\max \{ 0,w_k-y_k\}&=\cases{w_k-y_k & $w_k\geq y_k$\\0 &Otherwise}\\
\mathbb{E}\max \{ 0,w_k-y_k\}&=\sum_{w_k} (w_k-y_k)\cdot I(w_k\geq y_k)
\end{align}
where $I(\bullet)$ is the [Indicator Function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function).